# Why do parts of my string disappear when using "echo" in the shell?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, echo

I was trying to write something in a file via Linux command line using echo:

```
echo -e "<?php\nprint_r($_GET[\"name\"]);"     > print.php
```

But I get this:

```
<?php
print_r(["name"]);
```

What makes the `$_GET` disappear?

Comment: The `$` in linux is referencing a variable. Use `php -r`. Although the system isn't going to have `$_GET` populated.

Comment: So how to avoid that !

Comment: No I wanna write it into my file print.php

Comment: Use single quotes for the encapsulation. `echo -e '<?php\nprint_r($_GET[\"name\"]);'  > print.php`

Comment: No I can't I have only a permission to use double quotes as you see this is kinda of challenge in my university...

Comment: Wouldn't the challenge be more, er, challenging, if you tried to figure it out yourself?

Answer (score 2):

In bash, a dollar sign represents a variable, even inside of a string. To get it to print `$_GET`, you will have to escape the `$` with a backslash:

```
echo -e "<?php\nprint_r(\$_GET[\"name\"]);"     > print.php
```